# You are welcome

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

We say *thank you* when pleased with someone's help or attention. Usually it is replied: *you are welcome*.

**questions**

1. does it mean that *thanks* are welcome?
2. is it the same sense when we say you are welcome to somebody arriving at home?

Answer (score 2):

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/youre-welcome) defines **"you're welcome"** for English language learners as:

> You say **'You're welcome'** to someone who has thanked you for something in order to acknowledge their thanks in a polite way.

Additionally it is defined as:

> *In American*
>
> [Y]ou're under no obligation for the favor given;

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

> does it means that thanks are welcome?

When someone says "you're welcome", they usually mean that you **were welcome to** whatever you had thanked them for. For example, if the person had given you a cake and you said "thank you", if they respond "you're welcome" they're saying that you are **welcome to** the cake; that they are happy to give it to you. It is also often used to be polite to the person who said "thank you"; you can think of it as being almost like *thanking the person who said thank you.*

I hope this helps you. :)