# Is there some alternative use of "You are welcome"

Tags: phrases, slang

From what I have learned it's as described here
[You are welcome](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/163823/you-are-welcome)

But we use English as corp language at work, using slack and have GIPHY (a tool for adding GIFs to messages) connected to it and I give that phrase when helping people.
But if I GIPHY that phrase I get quite a few erotic suggestions, from people screwing in beds, images with the text "want to fuck" to the more okay "I want to kiss you all over".

Anyway, it's happened more than once that I sent those to managers of the other gender, and while it's a bit fun, especially after a hard week, and everyone can see what I intended to say. I wonder, is this just a fluke in GIPHY or is there some sexual meaning of that phrase and I do a fool of myself?

Comment: What is "giphy"?

Comment: @AIQ https://giphy.com/ it's a tool to add a funny animated image based on a word or phrase. For instance a `/giphy thanks` should generate a picture with a thumbs up, birthday cake or something similar related to the word/phrase.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the social appropriateness of a software application.

Comment: "You are welcome" is perfectly **free from any trace of the coarse or indecent** (in American English, [G--rated](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/G-rated).  Voting to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a quirk in Giphy, or more likely, that people who use it are using that particular GIF when they're searching which promotes it.

I'm a native speaker of American English, and a known potty mouth.  I've NEVER used *You're welcome* to mean *Want to fuck?*

*You are welcome* is a perfectly good way to respond to *thank you*.

More common in American English is to contract it to *You're welcome.*

Do not say *your* welcome.  This is ALWAYS wrong.

Also, in the US or with American clientele, using any of those GIFs could result in your termination.

Comment: Your last sentence is something of an exaggeration, as what is tolerated in client communications very much depends not only on the culture of the organizations, but on the relationship between the correspondents.

Comment: @choster given the nature of sexual harassment lawsuits and PC culture in the US, no it's not an exaggeration.  Even if you have that relationship with the client or co-workers, others can raise an objection on their behalf.

Answer (score 1):

"You're welcome" is a common response to "Thank you". I can't comment on the software you are using, but "you're welcome" doesn't have any sexual meaning that I am aware of.

It seems the software is fundamentally broken, and should not be used in a business context. I would recommend deleting it from all your systems urgently!

Alternatives include

> Don't mention it.
>
> It was nothing.
>
> That's okay.

All these express the idea that "You didn't need to say thank you". It is also not unusual not to respond formulaically to "thank you"

> — Hi John. Thank you for proofreading my report.
>
> — Oh yeah, I only found a couple of small mistakes. Mostly I thought it was pretty good.

John doesn't need to say "You are welcome". His response is natural and polite.